# R - How to pass variables to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot` to generate a scatter plot with a fitted line as follows

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=colNameX, y=colNameY)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method=loess, se=T, fullrange=F, size=1) + ylim(0,5)
```

Given this, want to generalize above into a function that takes the following arguments

```
scatterWithRegLine = function(df, xColName, yColName, regMethod, showSe, showFullrange, size, yAxisLim) {

  # How should I use the variables passed into the function above within ggplot
}
```

Such that I can call the function as follows

```
scatterWithRegLine(df, "mpg", "wt", "loess", TRUE, FALSE, 1, c(0,5))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using of `aes_string` is deprecated, you can use `sym` with `!!` :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

scatterWithRegLine = function(df, xColName, yColName, regMethod, showSe, showFullrange, size, yAxisLim) {
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x = !!sym(xColName), y = !!sym(yColName))) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method= regMethod, se=showSe, fullrange=showFullrange, size=size) + ylim(yAxisLim)
}
```

and then call it with

```
scatterWithRegLine(mtcars, "mpg", "wt", "loess", TRUE, FALSE, 1, c(0,5))
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. So much change happening in the tidyverse..

Comment: Yeah...I know. But I think `aes_string` was one of those function which was much simpler to use than it's successor.

Comment: All of this "tidyeval" stuff is getting ridiculous. It feels like functions get deprecated every month and replaced with something more opaque and less useful.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:** `aes_string()` works, however it is soft-deprecated now. Refer to @ronak-shah s answer, for a more up to date approach.

---

You could use `aes_string()` instead of `aes()` and pass the arguments as strings.

```r
require(ggplot2)

fun = function(dat, x, y, method) {
  ggplot(dat, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = method)
}

fun(iris,
    x = 'Sepal.Length', 
    y = 'Sepal.Width',
    method = 'loess')
```

Comment: how abt the rest ?

Comment: As long as it's outside of `aes_string()` and `aes()` it's passed anyway as a string. Or what do you mean?